# How much information should be shared between potential husband and wife before nikkah?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife

Suppose a girl has issues with her monthly cycle and she took some hormone treatment to fix it and she is satisfied with the treatment. However she walks into marriage without sharing this detail with her potential husband and his family because she didn't know it could be that much big of a deal. Her husband is a doctor, but is freaked out after finding out when she explains it casually. Now he's thinking of divorce just after 2 weeks saying it was deception, that nikkah is based upon a lie because it could cause a serious fertility issue.  However, it was discussed by the girl with various doctors and people who have gone through it and they said it is not a big deal can still be treated normal life continues.

This motivates the question:

How much information should be shared between potential husband and wife before marriage?

Comment: If the information does not affect normal life, the husband has the right to be upset and angry about hiding such information (because this info means the wife **may** have reproduction/fertility issues, I'm not a doctor), and if he wills to divorce, he has the right to do so.... **BUT** If the husband is slightly wise, and deeply loves his wife, and as long as this would have no effect on their future, he shall not go for divorce.

Comment: As for your question: Sharing as much info as they feel comfortable, AND any information that may affect the future of the relationship, or that may change the way your spouse sees you (for the better or worse). For example, I'd like to know if my fiance is not virgin (because that info could change the way I see her), but she doesn't need to tell me the details and number of her previous relationships (given that she had repented).

Answer (score 1):

Let me just come straight to your question and make it short. The details/questions needed to ask before marriage (whether male or female) is about his/her religion, character, virginity, and his/her will to get married. If a person lies about any of such thing and the spouse finds out after the marriage then it could be a serious issue.

Other than that, if a husband or wife wants to leave the marriage just because of financial issues or health issues then I think it is considered wrong. Because a person is solely responsible for religion, virginity, and character but not his/her health issues. Health and wealth are given to us by Allah and can be taken back too if He wills. A person can not punish someone for the things Allah has done.

In simple words, it is like blaming someone to be born as female instead of male. And that is sure insane.!

Answer (score -1):

I personally think these details are quite personal and the amount needed to be told is the woman is baligh and that is enough and if the family is comfortable to add more details up to them but it shouldnt be necessary I feel

Comment: And if the husband wants to know if the wife to be is a virgin he should honestly say if he is to?

Answer (score -1):

Transparency is key for marriage to work, maybe one man might not her to be his wife but another man who is better and more understanding will. These things should be shared but things that should not be shared are sins like adultery, even if they insist on you telling the truth, you must feel insulted and not let yourself reveal this. Allah does forgives everyone except those who share their major sins.

Answer (score -2):

In my humble opinion, people should share pre-existing health issues prior to marriage. As for this case, the doctors said the treatment the girl received is not a big deal so the husband is freaking out unnecessarily.

Answer (score -2):

I think it’s not such a big deal because you. Have just shared a health condition or some about your health to your family and not any inappropriate information so just be more careful ahead and yeah.

Answer (score -2):

As long as it is not something that directly affects him, everything that happened before marriage is between you and Allah and you have no obligation to share anything with him.

Comment: We are not a site for giving personal advice or peer support (see: https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/22). Please keep your answer focussed on the topic of Islam and answering the actual question, not for inserting subjective opinions on personal issues.